# Socket IO - Socket.emit is sent to all clients

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am creating a game using socket io. A player connects like this:

```
var playerName = document.getElementById("name").value;
socket.emit('setup player', {
    name : playerName
});
```

Then on the server, the player is setup and his information is sent back to the client:

```
function onSetupPlayer(data) {
    ...
    var newPlayer = new Player(x, y, color, data.name,
        this.id, scale);
    socket.emit('setup game', {
        localPlayer : newPlayer
    });
    ...
    sockets[this.id] = socket;
}
```

The following call:

```
socket.emit('setup game', {
        localPlayer : newPlayer
});
```

Should send the setup data only back to the client that requested the setup to be done originally. However the setup call gets send to everyone in the lobby.

Could this have anything to do with the fact that I am using localhost to test it? I am also testing it on the same machine by using different tabs. If this is what is causing the issue, is there a way to resolve it? Since this is pretty annoying when testing my game.

EDIT:
Initialization:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var socket = require('socket.io')(http);
var path = require('path');
var io = require('socket.io')(80);
...
var setEventHandlers = function() {
    socket.sockets.on("connection", onSocketConnection);
};
```

Listening for connection:

```
function onSocketConnection(client) {
    ...
    client.on("setup player", onSetupPlayer);
    ...
};
```

And on the client side I have this:

```
var setEventHandlers = function() {
    socket.on("setup game", onSetupGame);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`socket.emit` send event to everyone excepts this. To send data back to this user try

```
io.to(socket).emit()
```

Comment: var io = require('socket.io')(80)

Comment: Wil this still work when i upload to a server. Or only for local host?

Comment: Ok I have tried this, but now it is not being called at all.

Comment: you can show all socket.io code ?. May be problem in declare io and socket

Comment: In your code Io and socket is same thing, For send to user in this socket.to(client).emit(); You can remove  
var io = require('socket.io')(80)

Comment: How do I access client from in the setup function? Do I store it in a variable?

Comment: You can store client anywhere for small app you can push it to Array, every client have unique client.id for identify.